# Bulk inserting into MS SQL Server from irregular flat file

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm trying to bulk load in to a MS SQL table the value from a .txt file which are in quite a tricky format. The example below shows the first two sections of the file but this repeats over 100 times throughout the file. The headers are places at the top of each section. Is there any way I can handle this? The columns themselves are fixed length but I need to be able to tell SQL to take the values from the tables and ignore the headers. Any ideas at all?

Example of file format:

[image: Example screen shot here]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to show your coding skills here,what kind of help you want from us?

Comment: if you are asking for flow,it should be like this,1.get txt file into streamreader,2.split string by character | 3.if string[0]=choc_id then take data from nextline 4. insert and done.

Comment: Thanks Anand. I've not had any previous experience with SQL Stream so I was hoping I could handle this through a bulk insert script or an SSIS package. If I could get the contents of the data in the tables in to a SQL table I could do the rest of the work in a stored procedure. I'm just struggling to identify how to get it in but ignore the re-occurring headers.

Comment: You can use a SSIS package with the same ideas that I detailed in my answer. This brings you out of "bulk insert" territory though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no parameter or filter in bcp.exe or the `BULK INSERT` command that lets you filter out the unwanted rows. So you have to do either pre- or post-processing.

With preprocessing you write a tool in whatever language you know best to parse the input file and output another file that can serve as clean input to the bulk insert.

With postprocessing you load the file as it is into SQL Server (including the unwanted rows) and then delete the unwanted rows from the table. Depending on your needs you may want to use an intermediate (temporary) table for this.

First create a [format file](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191479.aspx) to use with the bulk insert. From your input it looks like you can use a fixed size format, which is good in this case. You could go badass, use a `date` column for the "END on" column in your table and just ignore any errors. Since none of the other rows seems to contain a valid date format, you could use this as a crude filter. All other ways you would need a table definition which uses (n)(var)char columns only.

With such a table you could just load the file then use a `WHERE` filter to remove anything invalid when transferring the data into the real table, like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyRealTable 
    SELECT CHOC_ID, EndOn, ... 
    FROM #TempBulkTable 
    WHERE CHOC_ID NOT IN ('untime', '---------------', ...)
```

Or you coul specify `FIRE_TRIGGERS` in your bulk insert and give the table an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger that does the filtering - though that kinda defeats the purpose of a bulk insert. If you use a temporary table make sure you have enough space in tempdb.

I hope this gives you some useful ideas.

Comment: Perfect. This has given me lots of inspiration. I love the date suggestion. I'll give it a go this afternoon.
Thanks so much.